# Keys vs shouldComponentUpdate, how are they related, are they not the same?

Tags: reactjs

How are key based optimisation (kbo) and shouldComponentUpdate (scu) related to eachother ?

They seem to be doing the same thing (avoid re-render and diffing).

How are they different? Am I missing something?

My feeling is that scu is "included" in key based optimisation ie. if a node has the same key as in previous render - on the same path of the tree - then it won't be re-rendered and this can be achieved with kbo too, but I am unsure.

What happens if a node has a path that does not match any path from the previous render and scu returns false, will the node then be re-rendered ? My guess is yes, not sure though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are definitely not the same.

`shouldComponentUpdate` controls whether `render` should run, that is, whether DOM diff and update are necessary. This check typically happens when `props`, `state`, or `context` are changed.

Keys are very different. By using the same `key`, you ensure that the same component instance is used. Consider the following:

```
<MyComponent title="Title 1" />
<MyComponent title="Title 2" />
```

If, for some reason, your `render` removes the first component and you end up with:

```
<MyComponent title="Title 2" />
```

Then what happens is that the second component is removed from DOM and the first one gets different properties, leading to rerender and DOM update.

If you use keys correctly:

```
<MyComponent key="key1" title="Title 1" />
<MyComponent key="key2" title="Title 2" />
```

after removal of the first component, the second one will receive the same props (will be rerendered depending on its `shouldComponentUpdate`) but most likely the only DOM update is the removal of the first component.

Thanks to `key`, React can do a minimal DOM update.

This has some serious implications, for example when using unmanaged components:

```
const MyComponent = () => {
   return <input defaultValue="some-text" />;
};
```

Again, when we have

```
<MyComponent title="Title 1" />
<MyComponent title="Title 2" />
```

and you write some text into the `input` of the first component, and then you remove the component, then the text will stay in the `<input>` even when it's the second component that contains it. Keys can prevent that.

Also note that when setting `key` to something that has not been rendered before, e.g.:

```
<MyComponent key="key3" />
```

a new instance of `MyComponent` is created, calling `componentDidMount`.
This can be used to completely reset the state of a component (e.g. for unmanaged inputs).

Most of the times you need to use `key` only in lists, to provide a performance boost when sorting, deleting etc. It has some secondary uses with unmanaged inputs but that's all.

To compare with `shouldComponentUpdate`, the key based optimizations are helping to match current render state to the previous one, thus preventing props from being changed.